# include a secondary file in main go file

Tags: file, go, include

I have a main.go file that I worked on and now I'm trying to organize since it became a little lengthy. I want to create a new file, put some functions in it and then include it in main.go and use those functions. That new file will be in the same directory as main.go. Anybody have any idea how to do this?

Answer (score 24, accepted):

As long as the go files are in the same package, you do not need to import anything.

Example:

**project/main.go:**

```
package main

import "fmt"

func main() {
    fmt.Println(sayHello())
}
```

**project/utils.go:**

```
package main

func sayHello() (string) {
    return "hello!"
}
```

To run: `go run main.go utils.go` or `go run *.go`

Comment: tried it, didn't work. it says "undefined : satHello

Comment: For `go run` you need to give it all the files as args. For example:

`go run main.go utils.go`

Comment: @matt.s it is too complex. If I have many files or I add a new file I need to enumerate all of them.

Comment: @AlexChaliy you could either pipe the output of the directory (like  `ls *.go`)
or maybe it's complicated enough to build and then run?

Comment: are here any ways to add tracking for where that say hello comes from i mean any alias or name if files gets up many

Answer (score 5):

You don't have to do any including (importing). Just use the same package name in both files.

Comment: and what if I want to organize everything in folders? it just works?

Comment: also, do I have to import all the libraries I am using every file or are they inherited?

Comment: All files in a package must be in the same directory, so each folder containing Go source files is a unique package. You then import those packages in other source files where they're needed. In each source file you have to import any package that is used in that source file. See https://golang.org/doc/code.html for more information about this. Also, I strongly suggest using the utility `goimports` to automatically manage the `import`s in your Go files (as well as doing what `gofmt`does, formatting your code in the standard way).

Comment: This isn't working for me with 1.12, I get an undefined function when using `go run main.go` where `main.go` and `help.go` both are in the same directory and are in the `main` package.

Comment: Try `go run main.go help.go`, `go run main`, or `go run .`.  You have to either give all the files or the package name or path.

Answer (score 0):

Old question, but no matter...

You can create `go.mod` file at the same directory you keep your source files with the help of following command:

```
go mod init main
```

This will create `mod` file for `main` package.

Each source file should start with `package main` directive.
After that you can build your project as follows:

```
go build .
```

And if you need build and run:

```
go run .
```